# Error: validation failed: unable to recognize "": no matches for kind "Deployment" in version ""

Tags: kubernetes-helm

Output of helm version:
Client: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.14.2", GitCommit:"a8b13cc5ab6a7dbef0a58f5061bcc7c0c61598e7", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Server: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.14.2", GitCommit:"a8b13cc5ab6a7dbef0a58f5061bcc7c0c61598e7", GitTreeState:"clean"}

Output of kubectl version:
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"10", GitVersion:"v1.10.11", GitCommit:"637c7e288581ee40ab4ca210618a89a555b6e7e9", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-11-26T14:38:32Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"windows/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"12", GitVersion:"v1.12.8", GitCommit:"a89f8c11a5f4f132503edbc4918c98518fd504e3", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-04-23T04:41:47Z", GoVersion:"go1.10.8", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

Cloud Provider/Platform (AKS, GKE, Minikube etc.):
AKS

Problem:
When i execute
helm install charts

i get the following error:
[debug] Created tunnel using local port: '51608'

[debug] SERVER: "127.0.0.1:51608"

[debug] Original chart version: ""
[debug] CHART PATH: C:\Users\akspoc\Downloads\SourceCode\develop-helm\akspoc\charts\akspoc

Error: validation failed: unable to recognize "": no matches for kind "Deployment" in version ""

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be with deployment YAML files inside the templates folder. Make sure the YAML is properly formatted.